# What is the "show side toolbar" key binding?

Tags: komodo

What is the "show side toolbar" key binding ?
i want to change "show side toolbar" key binding from key binding menu
this is in the left of the komodo panel
please help me everyone

thanks ahead

Comment: isn't any way guys !

Answer (score 0):

*Menu Edit (Komodo on OSX) > Preferences > Key Bindings: Search "show/hide all toolbars"*.  I don't know why it was called that.  You'll have better luck asking Komodo questions at https://community.komodoide.com/.

Here's a gif showing a little more detail. **NOTE**: *I select the second one of the two same entries (a bug)*. Once you have clicked *add* to add the key binding you just have to click *OK* or *Apply*.

[image]

Comment: FYI, use the second entry like I did in the gif.  You just help me stumble upon a bug in Komodo where two commands have the same description.